# How to loop within a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add a loop within a method in a Rails app. It looks something like this

```
Parent.do_something(
  attribute: "a string",
  parameter: "a string",
  child[0]: "child_url"
  )
```

Sometimes a parent will have no children. Sometime a parent will have x children. How can I create a loop within a function that will cycle through all these children.

I want something like

```
i=0
children=Child.all
Parent.do_something(
  attribute: "a string",
  parameter: "a string",
  for child in children
   child[i]: "child_url"
   i= i + 1
  end
  )
```

That will generate

```
Parent.do_something(
      attribute: "a string",
      parameter: "a string",
      child[0]: "child_0_url",
      child[1]: "child_1_url",
      child[2]: "child_2_url"
      )
```

If I have not explained this problem very clearly, I will update my question based on comments.

Comment: do you really need a key for each child? Or you just want to get an array of child_urls?

Comment: what are you actually trying to accomplish? right now it looks like you are trying to add a variable amount entries to a hash which is then passed to a class method

Comment: yes, I will need a key for each entry. I've updated the question, apologies for being unclear, I'm struggling how to explain this clearly (or even whether it is possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested, it might be better to redesign your method to expect an array of children, rather than lots of single parameters :

```
Parent.do_something(
  attribute: "a string",
  parameter: "a string",
  children: ["child_0_url", "child_1_url", "child_2_url"]
  )
```

But if you *have* to do it the way you said (for instance, if you're constrained by someone else's poor API):

```
children = Child.all
Parent.do_something(
  {attribute: "a string",
   parameter: "a string"}.merge Hash[*(children.each_with_index.map { |child, i| ["child[#{i}]", child.url] }.flatten)]
)
```

Ugly, huh?

As the saying goes; if it's hard to do, you're probably doing it wrong. The nice flat map of Ismael Abreu's answer is much prettier.

Comment: Agree with you that it's ugly, and definitely not my preferred approach, but this is exactly the answer I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You might just want to do this:

```
children = Child.all
Parent.do_something(
  attribute: "a string",
  parameter: "a string",
  child: children.map { |child| child.url }
)
```

Comment: +1 assuming that `child.url` is valid. Hopefully it gives the OP enough info on how to use `map` properly.

Comment: thanks for this advice. However I need to generate a variable number of child objects, i.e. `child[0]: xxxxx, child[1]: yyyyyy, child[2]: .....` This is the part that is causing me confusion!

Comment: What this gives you is something like `child: [xxx, yyy]`. You still have the same data but inside an array so you can access it easier. You might not be familiar with the `map` method, it basically let you create a new array doing something to the elements of your current array, applying the block you provide to it. In this case I call the `url` method on a child (I'm just supposing there is such method) and then I get an array of the children urls, with the same order.

Comment: And this will work for any number of children you have, if you have 1 it will be something like `child: ['child_url']`, if none `child: []`, ....

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier to extract that part into a different method:

```
Parent.do_something(
  attribute: "a string",
  parameter: "a string",
  children: children_method
)

def children_method
  Parent.children.map do |child|
     # whatever needs to be done
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to pass a variable number of arguments to a method, you're probably looking for the [splat (*) operator](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/).

Comment: This is a useful tip! Not exactly what I'm looking for here, but good to learn anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the urls like you typed them, try this:

```
children = Child.all
Parent.do_something(
  attribute: "a string",
  parameter: "a string",
  child: something
)

def something
  child = []
  children.length.times { |index| child << "child_#{index}_url"}
  return child
end
```

You could also replace children.length with Child.count if you don't need the children elsewhere, but I'm assuming you do.

Edit: I think this may be **more what you are looking for**:

```
children = Child.all
Parent.do_something(
  attribute: "a string",
  parameter: "a string",
  child: children.each_with_index.map { |child,i| "child_#{i}_#{child.url}"}
)
```

This takes advantage of the fact that each_with_index returns an Enumerator if no block is given.